# How to export to excel only items filtered on my view

Tags: 2013, excel, export

In my specific list, I filtered to a account we are going to pay.  Then when I click on "Export to Excel" button all the items of the list gets exported. How would I export data that I want?

Example: Because we cannot filter on the JPP number, we first filter on area = Northeast then filter on Muni = Granville T & V then filter on JPP # 801000024716  then I go to list and click on xport to xcel.... it takes about a minute then we get a list of many, many jpps.... not just the one.

Our hope was to export to excel the info on the view and just give it to the billing clerk so she can pay the bill using the view info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to create a new View with whatever filter you currently have and then exporting to spread sheet will only contain the relevant items.

Comment: The filtering has to be done in modify view correct ?

Comment: Yes create a new view.. and then use the filter section to specify your filter.